# How can I port PHP preg_split to Java for the special case of unserializing a value in ADODB?

Tags: java, php, regex, adodb

I need to port this function for unserializing a value in ADODB to Java.

```
        $variables = array( );
        $a = preg_split( "/(\w+)\|/", $serialized_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY |   PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $a ); $i = $i+2 ) {
            $variables[$a[$i]] = unserialize( $a[$i+1] );
        }
```

I have a library to unserialize the values the php way, but I need help on porting over the preg_split. What would this regex look like in Java?

Comment: We're going to need some examples of inputs and desired outputs.  There's no easy way to translate that code to Java.  You'll probably have to take a different approach, using `find()` rather than `split()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent java code :

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// Test
String serialized_string = "foo|bar|coco123||cool|||";

// Split the test
String[] raw_results=serialized_string.split("\\|");// Trailing empty strings are removed but not internal ones

// Cleansing of the results
List<String> php_like_results = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String tmp : raw_results) {
    if (tmp.length()>0) {
       php_like_results.add(tmp);
    }
}

// Output results
System.out.println(php_like_results);
```

This will produce :
`[foo, bar, coco123, cool]`

Comment: While this works for the specifc example given in the question, one has to be careful though, as Java doesn't know any `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option and doesn't capture the delimiters.